# Android kills my service need understanding CPU stats

Tags: android

Android kills my service in the package com.net.myspeechservice under some certain scenarios, for example when there is a call on the phone it kills the service. The logcat show me these statistics.

As it seems quite obvious that it got killed because of CPU load.

What I don't get is which percentage of CPU consumption was caused by my app ??? it's not being shown  at all.

I don't get following means ?

```
Load: 3.13 / 2.78 / 2.26
```

How can I asses from these stats as to what percentage was caused by my app.

please advise.

thanks,

```
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): ANR in com.net.myspeechservice
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): Reason: Executing service com.net.myspeechservice/.services.ManagementService
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): Load: 3.13 / 2.78 / 2.26
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): CPU usage from 10340ms to 0ms ago:
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   44% 178/com.android.phone: 43% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 179 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   25% 36/surfaceflinger: 21% user + 3.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   10% 38/mediaserver: 8.1% user + 2.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   5.1% 1496/android.process.acore: 2.8% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 3984 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   3.3% 150/com.android.systemui: 3.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   1.9% 45/adbd: 0.2% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 420 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   0.6% 88/system_server: 0.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   0% 6391/ekawas.blogspot.com: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 40 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   0.1% 35/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): 100% TOTAL: 82% user + 17% kernel + 0.1% softirq
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): CPU usage from 1521ms to 2139ms later:
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   41% 178/com.android.phone: 40% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     50% 178/m.android.phone: 48% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 235/RILReceiver: 1.6% user + 0% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   29% 36/surfaceflinger: 22% user + 6.4% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     22% 61/SurfaceFlinger: 19% user + 3.2% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 36/surfaceflinger: 1.6% user + 0% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 63/Binder Thread #: 1.6% user + 0% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 109/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 1283/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   16% 38/mediaserver: 11% user + 4.9% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     6.5% 1551/gle.mp3.decoder: 4.9% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     3.2% 1553/AudioTrackThrea: 1.6% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 72/AudioOut_1: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     1.6% 1552/OMXCallbackDisp: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   9.6% 88/system_server: 4.8% user + 4.8% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     8% 103/ActivityManager: 4.8% user + 3.2% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):   1.6% 1496/android.process.acore: 0% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 196 minor
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88):     3.3% 1542/ApplicationsPro: 0% user + 3.3% kernel
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): 100% TOTAL: 82% user + 17% kernel
```

Comment: Actually, CPU load doesn't matter. This message states that your app/service didn't respond timely on user input hence got killed by framework.
ANR in com.net.myspeechservice
06-21 06:44:35.042: E/ActivityManager(88): Reason: Executing service com.net.myspeechservice/.services.ManagementService
ANR - Application Not Responding. Or also called app freezes sometimes. They occur if your activity doesn't handle touches fast enough. You need to check your app's logic to see if there is a place which does some long calculations or any deadlocks.

Comment: Actually it does not mae sense because this occurs when there is an incoming call, my activity is not even visible. However I have a Service running only ..

Comment: "com.net.myspeechservice" Is this your package? Just want to make it clear. The log shows an ANR issue in this package. If your package is different, then this log has nothing to do with your service being killed. In this case the reason for your service to die is that android ran out of free memory and decided to kill what can be killed (background apps and not critical services). This can happen, and you need to be ready. However, you can make your service automatically re-start after being killed. For this you should return START_STICKY from onStartCommand() of your service.

Comment: And one more status update: ANR can be also caused by a service. If your service received some broadcast and hasn't finished its processing within 10 seconds, ANR will be issued. There was some detailed explanation about ANR reasons in android's doc page... google for it.

Comment: @alex.veprik Thanks alex, restarting won't help because the functionality of the service is to do text to speech exactly in this scenario/use case when it gets killed. Wierd thing is other apps taking more memory are not killed. I had though it was CPU rise I noted that as soon as my app starts to take CPU and appears somewhere at position 7 in top 10 cpu using processes it gets killed

Comment: Just realised if restart is quick my service still have a chance to check if conditions are favorable to operate ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load line is showing you the amount of CPU cores required to operate all threads in real time. I.e. a load of 1 means that you are fully utilising a single core over that period. A Load of 5 means you would need five cores to operate in real time, or if you have two cores you are overloading them by 150%.

```
Load: X / Y / Z
```

Load is shown as three numbers to give the load over different timeframes. It is typically given as 1 minute, 5 minutes and fifteen minutes.

Without knowing the package name of your app though I can't begin to look at the rest of the log. Although at a guess it is `ekawas.blogspot.com` (which is missing from the second snapshot) which would indicate that CPU load from your app isn't an issue. It might however be a memory issue.